# Google Assistant triggers "Default Fallback Intent" while Dialogflow does not

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I created a chatbot which contains only one additional intent (`depr_intent`) along with the `Default Welcome Intent` and the `Default Fallback Intent`. This intent includes only the following training phrase: "What causes a person to get depressed and how can this be treated?". I set the `ML CLASSIFICATION THRESHOLD` to 0.2 .

When I enter on Dialogflow "I am a depressed person" then the `depr_intent` is triggered and the json response from Dialogflow is the following:

```
{
  "id": "*****************************",
  "timestamp": "2018-04-17T12:41:07.662Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "I am a depressed person",
    "action": "5",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {},
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "*****************************",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 253,
      "intentName": "depr_intent"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "...",
      "source": "agent",
      "displayText": "...",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "..."
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 0.25
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "****************************"
}
```

Notice at the json response above that the score of this question is `0.25` .However, when I am entering the exact same phrase ("I am a depressed person") on Google Assistant (after entering "Talk to my test app" and getting triggered the `Default Welcome Intent`) then the `Default Fallback Intent` is triggered which responds "Sorry I did not find anything relevant to your question" and not the `depr_intent`. The `DEBUG` section on Google Assistant contains the following:

```
{
  "response": "Sorry I did not find anything relevant to your question.",
  "expectUserResponse": 1,
  "conversationToken": "CiZDIzVhZD...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAARsA...",
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=*************************' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: [token]'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"*************************\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-04-17T12:46:56Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1523969239924\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"I am a depressed person\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"I am a depressed person\",\"textValue\":\"I am a depressed person\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"A****************************\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-04-17T12:46:56Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1523969239924\",\"type\":\"ACTIVE\",\"conversationToken\":\"[]\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.TEXT\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"I am a depressed person\"}],\"arguments\":[{\"name\":\"text\",\"rawText\":\"I am a depressed person\",\"textValue\":\"I am a depressed person\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}"
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"conversationToken\":\"[]\",\"expectUserResponse\":true,\"expectedInputs\":[{\"inputPrompt\":{\"richInitialPrompt\":{\"items\":[{\"simpleResponse\":{\"textToSpeech\":\"Sorry I did not find anything relevant to your question.\"}}]}},\"possibleIntents\":[{\"intent\":\"assistant.intent.action.TEXT\"}],\"speechBiasingHints\":[\"$Employee_names_MP\",\"$Employee_names_JT\",\"$Greeting_type\",\"$Objective_whoswho\",\"$Locations\"]}],\"responseMetadata\":{\"status\":{\"message\":\"Success (200)\"},\"queryMatchInfo\":{}}}"
    },
    "sharedDebugInfoList": []
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Sorry I did not find anything relevant to your question."
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/voice/opa/partner_icons/generic_3p_avatar.png"
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": 1
}
```

Why is this happening?

Actually, even if I set the `ML CLASSIFICATION THRESHOLD` to 0.05 the same thing is happening on Google Assistant. Moreover, keep in mind that if I enter on Google Assistant "what causes a person to get depressed" then `depr_intent` is triggered (and apparently the same applies on Dialogflow). Finally, note that the fact that I am using a webhook at this basic bot does not make a difference (I think) since the same intents are triggered even without the webhook.

**

### UPDATE

**

When I enter on Google Assistant "Why am I a person depressed" which has a score of  `0.2800000011920929` (remember the `ML CLASSIFICATION THRESHOLD` is 0.2) then `depr_intent` is triggered. Personally, I am inclined to believe that Google Assistant has a minimum `ML CLASSIFICATION THRESHOLD` of `0.25`. However, I entered two different phrases which each had score `0.25` and Google Assistant triggered `depr_intent` at the one and `Default Fallback Intent` at the other of them (while both triggered `depr_intent` on Dialogflow). Hence, I do not really know what is happening. But if we accept that probably there is a `0.25` minimum `ML CLASSIFICATION THRESHOLD` on Google Assistant then it may be that the former phrase was a bit above `0.25` and the latter one was a bit below `0.25` .

Comment: You say this is the only Intent. Do you have a welcome intent? Or is this the only one after the welcome Intent?

Comment: Thank you for your question. You are right I did not write this properly. See the first sentence of my edited post please. ("I created a chatbot which contains only one additional intent (depr_intent) along with the Default Welcome Intent and the Default Fallback Intent")

Comment: (Dear @Prisoner, do you have any idea why this is happening from what I said so far?)

Comment: If I did, I would have replied. {: I don't, and I haven't had a chance to do some testing yet. Your supposition makes sense, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Haha, ok, I get it. No worries. I am simply impressed to discover all these differences between Dialogflow and Google Assistant which are also not documented at all.

Comment: Why not add more training sentences into your intent? That way the score would be way higher. You don't need to add many for Dialogflow to perform really well...